# How to write page.tpl.php header section

Tags: theming

I am using bootstrap subtheme with drupal 7.I have a requirement to design the header as following:

[image]

My tpl file looks like this:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
// copy the header code here from the default page.tpl.php
</div>
<div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
// login block goes here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have done google searches. I am still not sure if I did it correctly. Can you please advise?

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: I am just not sure if I wrote my tpl file correctly. I just like to double check with you if it is the correct way to write responsive tpl file. Please let me know if it is correct or need to modify. Thanks.

Comment: do you want logo and main-menu together in same column? to get a space before login column use col-offset to skip columns.

Comment: I did show you the design. I am asking for your recommendations. I am not sure it should be in same column or row. I am confused. If you can help me some code, it would help.